# how to add colour diff in git send-email

Tags: python, git, sendmail, git-send-email

I am using git send-email command, but the diff patch is not colored.

If I try `git send-email -1 --color` it send ANSI colour code in email and unformatted text.

I want to be able to mail color diff patch.

Comment: How exactly would that work? As HTML? How would the recipient apply the patch?

Comment: Technically, the patch is colored. The mail client you are using just doesn't understand how to interpret ANSI color codes.

Comment: i am not using mail client, the email is sent by `git send-email` command that adds the diff in email but it is not colour formatted.

Comment: Since send-email is not that popular (and the official Git flow does not accept HTML emails as patches) this is a feature that has been ignored. I agree that it would be a great one. About @Chris concern about how to apply the patch, both, HTML and Plain Text formats must be sent (as ususal). The patch can then be applied using the Plain Text content while letting the user check the HTML version.